# Form validation common error message for 2 input fields

Tags: javascript, validation

Have a form validator and want to get common error message for the following both input fields. Is this possible:

```
<select id="category" name="category" onchange="showSelected1();" style="width:160px">
    <option value="00"><font color="#999999">Category</font></option>
    <option value="1">Marriages</option>
    <option value="2">Birthdays</option>
</select>

<select id="city" name="city" onchange="showSelected();" style="width:160px">
    <option value="000"><font color="#999999">City</font></option>
    <option value="1">New York</option>
    <option value="2">Washington</option>
</select>
```

And used gen_validatorv4.js.

```
var frmvalidator= new Validator("frm1");
frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
frmvalidator.addValidation("category","dontselect=00","Select Category");
frmvalidator.addValidation("city","dontselect=000","Select City");
```

Want to get error message like "Select category and city". (only one error message for both)

Answer (score 0):

According to this URL, you can build custom validation functions with gen_validatorv4.js:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml

So try something like this:

```
function DoCustomValidation() {
  if (document.getElementById('category').value == "00" || document.getElementById('city').value == "000") {
      var element;

      if (document.getElementById('category').value == "00") {
         element = document.getElementById('category');
      }
      else {
         element = document.getElementById('city');
      }

      sfm_show_error_msg("Select category and city", element);

      return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}  

frmvalidator.setAddnlValidationFunction("DoCustomValidation");
```

Comment: did you try this setAddnlValidationFunction ? It is not working for me. I don't see any error as well. If I keep the quotes around function name, it asks me to remove that, but after that no javascript in page works.